# Show random xml files in Android

Tags: android, layout, random

In my Android app i click on the "random" button and the app shows me a random xml file out of first.xml, second.xml or third.xml. This works all fine but i wondered if there is an easier or a nicer way to implement it if you have 100+ xml files.

I found some code (which works fine) which shows random ImageViews:

```
    private Integer [] mImageIds = { 
        R.drawable.one, 
        R.drawable.two, 
        R.drawable.three, 
        };
   private static final Random rgenerator = new Random();

   private ImageView iv;

   .
   .
   .

   Integer q = mImageIds[rgenerator.nextInt(mImageIds.length)];

   iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewyeah);
   iv.setImageResource(q);
```

This is how my main.xml looks:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/first_button"
        android:onClick="change"
        android:text="first"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/second_button"
        android:onClick="change"
        android:text="second"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/third_button"
        android:onClick="change"
        android:text="third"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/random_button"
        android:onClick="change"
        android:text="random"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

and this is the code which is processed when you click on a button:

```
    package com.random;

    import java.util.Random;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;

    public class Main extends Activity {
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

public void change(final View view){
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.first_button:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstPage.class));
        break;
    case R.id.second_button:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondPage.class));
        break;
    case R.id.third_button:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ThirdPage.class));
        break;
    case R.id.random_button:

        Random random = new java.util.Random();
        int rand = random.nextInt(3);

        switch (rand) {
        case 0:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstPage.class));
            break;
        case 1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondPage.class));
            break;
        case 2:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ThirdPage.class));
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

---

Now I've got a fairly similar question. So far i implemented a "Random"-button. If you click on it a random xml-file will be shown. Note: The content (TextViews, ImageViews) are different in the xml-files but the java code (clicking on buttons etc.) is the same!

That's the code if you click on the "Random"-button:

```
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.first_button:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, FirstPage.class));
        break;
    case R.id.second_button:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondPage.class));
        break;
    case R.id.third_button:
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ThirdPage.class));
        break;
    case R.id.random_button:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayRandomPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

and this is in the DisplayRandomPage.class

```
    public class DisplayRandomPage extends Activity {

private Integer [] mLinearLayoutIds = { 
        R.layout.one
        R.layout.two,
        R.layout.three
        };

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 


    Random random = new java.util.Random();
    int rand = random.nextInt(3);

    setContentView(mLinearLayoutIds[rand]);
            }
    }
```

What i'd like to do is creating a DisplaySpecificPage.class. Above I've shown my main.class with the switch-case-clause. So when i click on the first button, it will start the FirstPage.class, clicking the second, it will start SecondPage.class, and so on. So for each xml-file i have to create a new java-class although the different java-classes do all the same. Only the xml-files are different. So i'd like to put something like this:

pseudo-code:

```
    case R.id.first_button:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, DisplaySpecificPage.class)) with R.layout.first_page;
    break;
```

how do i pass the ID from the layout (R.layout.first_page) on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your classes all do the same thing except have a different layout called, you could create a single display class

```
public class DisplayPage extends Activity
```

and send it the id of the layout in the intent extras.

You can get the id by doing something like

```
Class c = Class.forName("com.random.R$layout");
Integer iLayout = new Integer(c.getField("layout"+rand).getInt(new R.layout()));
```

(assuming your layouts are called layout1.xml, layout2.xml etc.)

Send it to your DisplayPage,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayPage.class);
intent.putExtra("Layout", iLayout);
startActivity(intent);
```

and get it back by doing something like

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // default value
  int iLayout = R.id.main;

  if (savedInstanceState != null)
  {
    iLayout = savedInstanceState.getInt("Layout");
  }
  else
  {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null)
    {
      iLayout = extras.getInt("Layout");
    }
  }

  setContentView(iLayout);

}
```

You'll also want to override onSaveInstanceState to include that int so that, e.g., changing the screen orientation doesn't make it forget what it was showing.

---

```
try
{
  Class c = Class.forName("com.random.R$layout");
  Field[] aFields = c.getFields();

  Random random = new Random();      
  boolean isUsableLayout = false;
  Integer iLayout = 0;

  while (!isUsableLayout)
  {
    int rand = random.nextInt(aFields.length);      
    iLayout = new Integer(c.getField(aFields[rand].getName()).getInt(new R.layout()));

    if (iLayout != R.layout.main)
    {
      isUsableLayout = true;
    }
  }

  Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayPage.class);
  intent.putExtra("Layout", iLayout);
  startActivity(intent);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben!
I did what you posted and it works! But i renamed those three sample layouts into layout1, layout2, ... in fact my layouts dont have such similar names. I was thinking of doing something like this:
 private Integer [] mLinearLayoutIds = { 
        R.id.one, 
        R.id.two, 
        R.id.three, 
        };
do you have a clue how this would work?

Comment: You could use `Field[] afFields = c.getFields()` to return all the layout ids as a Fields array, pick one of those at random, check it isn't a layout you don't want to use (eg, main), and use that.  Otherwise you would have to hand write all hundred+ layout ids into your array.

Comment: Hi again! It seems that im stuck here. never really used Fields before. So this is the code snippet in my switch-case-clause "now": `Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.random.R$layout"); java.lang.reflect.Field[] afFields = c.getFields();` Now I dont know how to pass it on to the DisplayPage.class and dont know how to use it there then. Finally id like to know if i have to check for layouts i dont want to be shown (e.g. main) if i dont give the layouts an ID or am i totally wrong there. If so how do i check for unwanted layouts? like this: `(if afFields == main) then randomize again ` Thanks!!!

Comment: Edited original comment with example.  All created layouts are given an id and added to R.layout automatically at build time.

Comment: Done! This works fine! Thanks a lot for that! Now just one last question for the future if i might need it once. What would i have to write if i use an Integer Array like this `private Integer [] mLinearLayoutIds = { R.id.one, R.id.two, R.id.three, }` ? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask.  To create the array, you'd want `Integer[] mLIds = { R.layout.one, R.layout.two, R.layout.three };`  To use it, you'd use `mLIds[index]`, noting that array indexes start at 0, so that mLIds[0] = R.layout.one, mLids[1] = R.layout.two and so on.

Comment: Works! That was exactly what i asked for! Appreciate your help!